# How to print to the java stack trace console in an Eclipse plugin?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am creating a plugin for Eclipse and I'd like to print messages AND exceptions in the "Java Stack Trace Console". I am creating a new MessageConsole to print the messages, but the exceptions stack trace is printed in plain text, without the links to classes and methods.

How does it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If in your launching configuration arguments (or command line) you will add -consoleLog parameter then the logging (which is writen in {workspace}/.metadata/.log file) will also be duplicated to console.
The stack traces are navigable from there.